# How to find the accuracy for Survival Analysis using RandomForestSRC package in R

Tags: r, random-forest, survival-analysis

I'm using randomForestSRC package in R for creating Survival Forest. I have Training and Tesing datasets.
By using Training dataset, trees are grown (Random Forest)  and using Testing set, prediction is made.

Now I wanted to get the accuracy of the predicted survival output.I could get the error rate parameter from the prediction output.But do not know whether that is the accuracy of the model or we have to calculate accuracy from it.

When I searched for the same, I could see that accuracy for normal random forest can be calculated using confusion matrix. But not sure how to calculate accuracy for survival output.

Kindly let me know, how to calculate accuracy of the RandomForest Survival Model.

Comment: Hello, have you found a solution to create a confusion matrix with rfsrc object ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

In RandomForest, you do not need to divide it into training and test data as you would calculate OOB Error. Posting few links that should be helpful

[OOB Error explained - Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-out-of-bag-error-in-Random-Forests)

[How OOB Estimation Works - Breiman*](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/OOBestimation.pdf)

[OOB Explained quite well - ETH](http://stat.ethz.ch/education/semesters/ss2012/ams/slides/v10.2.pdf)

[Leo Breiman and Adele Cutler - The out-of-bag (oob) error estimate
In random forests, there is no need for cross-validation or a separate test set to get an unbiased estimate of the test set error. It is estimated internally, during the run, as follows:

Each tree is constructed using a different bootstrap sample from the original data. About one-third of the cases are left out of the bootstrap sample and not used in the construction of the kth tree.

Put each case left out in the construction of the kth tree down the kth tree to get a classification. In this way, a test set classification is obtained for each case in about one-third of the trees. At the end of the run, take j to be the class that got most of the votes every time case n was oob. The proportion of times that j is not equal to the true class of n averaged over all cases is the oob error estimate. This has proven to be unbiased in many tests.][4](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/RandomForests/cc_home.htm)